# How to use linq with enum type

Tags: c#, linq, enums

In our project, we have a piece of code which look like this:

```
return (productEvents.Where(s => event.Equals(s.Type)));
```

where `event` and `s.Type` both belong to an enum type EventType.

But when running, it throws an exception with this message

> Unable to cast the type 'EventType' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to
>   Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: What is `event` here? how u defines the `enum`

Comment: You cant use event as variable name, you must use @event, because event is a keyword in C#

Comment: Type means the type of object s i think you either have the typo or you should not have enum named type

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro, actually in the code it is not "event", but because of our company policy, i have to change the variable name

Comment: Have you tried `s => s.Type == event` instead use Equals method?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro, after change it to ==, it works, but do you know why it does not work with Equals ?

Comment: @TuAnh because Equals method try to convert parameter into object tipe :D

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your current code into this:

```
return (productEvents.Where(s => event == s.Type));
```

It should work. When you use Equals method, Linq to entities will try to create a sql query from your expression, and when you use Equals method, it will try to convert the cast, and LINQ to Entities doest support that.